# munin requires perl(RRDs)

Tags: rhel6, munin

I'm in RHEL6.3 and I'm installing munin from epel  http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm I already solved all dependencies except this one :

```
Error: Package: perl-Log-Log4perl-1.30-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(RRDs)
Error: Package: munin-2.0.21-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(RRDs)
```

I already installed `rrdtool` from repo local, but it's still showing this error.

```
Name        : rrdtool
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.3.8
Release     : 6.el6
Size        : 699 k
Repo        : installed
```

Could someone help...
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The package you need is called `rrdtool-perl` and should be in the base repo:

```
yum install rrdtool-perl
```

Which you can also install using the virtual dependency mentionen in the error:

```
yum install 'perl(RRDs)'
```

Comment: I tried this but no package available :

$ yum install rrdtool-perl

Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Base                                                     |  951 B     00:00
dvd                                                      | 4.0 kB     00:00
epel/metalink                                            | 1.5 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package rrdtool-perl available.

Comment: I tried this but no package available :

'$yum install rrdtool-perl'

No package rrdtool-perl available.'

I downloaded the rpm package but requiring rrdtool even rrdtool is installed: 

'$ rpm -ivh rrdtool-perl-1.3.8-9.1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        librrd.so.4()(64bit) is needed by rrdtool-perl-1.3.8-9.1.x86_64
        rrdtool = 1.3.8-9.1 is needed by rrdtool-perl-1.3.8-9.1.x86_64'

Answer (score 0):

The `rrdtool-perl` package in RHEL6.6 needs repositories "`rhel-6-server-eus-optional-rpms`" and "`rhel-6-server-eus-rpms`" enabled.

With user root you can use `subscription-manager` or `subscription-manager-gui` to add and enable repositories.